# Connect to a Redis SignalR server using a windows service

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

So i have taken a look at this: http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-net-client#establishconnection in order to create a connection to signalr on my windows service, but I have recently just started using redis as my signalR server.  What would a connection to a redis server look like in a windows service?  Code example would help, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can set up Redis as a Windows Service, this doc has information on setting up Redis as a Windows Service and using Redis in SignalR app:  https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/SignalR-with-Redis-Running-on-a-Windows-Azure-Virtual-Machine